# Custom Model Binder with Contructor and FromForm

Tags: model-binding, .net-7.0

I have a model with a constructor that I am passing into a controller

```
public sealed CheckinForm
{
     private readonly IBookingQuery _bookingQuery;

     public CheckinForm(IBookingQuery bookingQuery)
     { 
        _bookingQuery = bookingQuery;
     }
     
     public DateTime Checkin {get;set;}
     public DateTime Checkout {get;set;}
     public int NumberOfAdults {get;set;}
}
```

I am doing a json post to the controller and using .net 7.0.

The default model binder is no longer in use in .net 7.0.

I am looking at writing a custom model builder to handle the constructor.

When I am using [FromForm] in .net by default is the FormCollectionModelBinder used.

I want a generic binder that iterates all Form values and binds to the model and am unsure whether to inherit from FormCollectionModelBinder in this instance.